# Read MySQL data into Bootstrap 4 columns

Tags: php, mysql, grid

Welcome Forum residents,

My goal is to display MySQL data in input cards and the cards aligned side by side in bootstrap 4 rows.

Reading MySQL data works fine, but the input cards are not juxtaposed by the Bootstrap 4 grid system. (If I do not read data from MySQL, I only use plain HTML, the Grid system works.)

The code:

```
...
        <?php include_once('includes/head.tpl'); ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php include_once('includes/php/navbar.php'); ?>
            <form method="GET" action="action2.php">
        <?php
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM plans");
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        ?>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <label>
                                <input type="radio" name="plan_id" id="plan_id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="card-input-element" />
                                <div class="card-input">
                                    <?php echo $row['plan_name']; ?><br>
                                    <?php echo $row['plan_cpu']; ?><br>
                                    <?php echo $row['plan_memory']; ?><br>
                                    <?php echo $row['plan_disk']; ?><br>
                                </div>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
         <?php   
            }  
        ?>
        <input type="submit" name="btn-submit">
            </form>  
         </div>

...
```

The end result:

[image]

What could be the problem? 
Why is  Grid system not working when reading MySQL?

Thanks in advance for the answers!

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem looks like you create the bootstrap container div and row element for each row of the data, this should be outside of the loop where you retrieve the rows...

```
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row"> 
    <?php    
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM plans");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    ?>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="plan_id" id="plan_id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="card-input-element" />
                            <div class="card-input">
                                <?php echo $row['plan_name']; ?><br>
                                <?php echo $row['plan_cpu']; ?><br>
                                <?php echo $row['plan_memory']; ?><br>
                                <?php echo $row['plan_disk']; ?><br>
                            </div>
                        </label>
                    </div>
     <?php   
        }  
     ?>
                </div>
            </div>
```

If you have more plans that fit on a row, you would need to create the div's  for the row each time you get to the split point.

Comment: Ohh, thanks for the super quick answer!
The solution is right, I wasn't paying attention enough. :)

Comment: If there is no result you will get error. Declare $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) and before while ask isset($row) && count($row) > 0 to be sure that data exist and suppress errors.